# How to Create 2D array in javascript with json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc framework and i have json data which i want to in 2d array.
Here is my data.

**Json data(Input data)**

```
var data=[{"ID":1,"Min":80,"Max":175},{"ID":2,"Min":90,"Max":240},{"ID":3,"Min":90,"Max":215},{"ID":4,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":5,"Min":70,"Max":190},{"ID":6,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":7,"Min":70,"Max":140},{"ID":8,"Min":80,"Max":160}];
```

I need to get Min and Max values from Json data.

**Required output:**

```
data=[[80,175],[90,240],[90,215],[50,120],[70,190],[50,120],[70,140],[80,160]]
```

Waiting for your response

Comment: Just a note, there are some SO Elite's, that will hammer you down for saying that's JSON data.  It's not, it's a javascript object, if you left out the `var data=` and the trailing `;`, then I would say it's JSON. :)

Comment: [json](http://json.org/) is a string. always.

Comment: Indeed, take out the bits I just said, and it's a string.

Comment: @PrateekJairath Could you please respond to the answers below? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `map()`

```js
var data=[{"ID":1,"Min":80,"Max":175},{"ID":2,"Min":90,"Max":240},{"ID":3,"Min":90,"Max":215},{"ID":4,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":5,"Min":70,"Max":190},{"ID":6,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":7,"Min":70,"Max":140},{"ID":8,"Min":80,"Max":160}];

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  return [e.Min, e.Max];
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map  (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ )

```
var o = {"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"};

var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) { return o[k] });

console.log(arr)
```

here an example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/67/

Answer (score 0):

```
var data=[{"ID":1,"Min":80,"Max":175},{"ID":2,"Min":90,"Max":240},{"ID":3,"Min":90,"Max":215},{"ID":4,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":5,"Min":70,"Max":190},{"ID":6,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":7,"Min":70,"Max":140},{"ID":8,"Min":80,"Max":160}];

var data1 = [];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  var temp = [];
  temp.push(data[i].Min);
  temp.push(data[i].Max);
  data1.push(temp);
}
```

Now data1 is your required array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` to create the resulting array of arrays:

```js
var data=[{"ID":1,"Min":80,"Max":175},{"ID":2,"Min":90,"Max":240},{"ID":3,"Min":90,"Max":215},{"ID":4,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":5,"Min":70,"Max":190},{"ID":6,"Min":50,"Max":120},{"ID":7,"Min":70,"Max":140},{"ID":8,"Min":80,"Max":160}];

var result = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  prev.push([curr.Min, curr.Max]);
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```